# Periodic slow wifi pings on android despite strong signal

Tags: networking, wi-fi

I have an android phone connected to my home wireless. Every other device in the house works ok with the network. Checking ping in Android adb shows some weird results:

```
Android:/ $ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1211 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=205 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=22.3 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=1068 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=62.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=1109 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=58 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=1146 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=58 time=138 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=58 time=1183 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=58 time=176 ms
```

I am getting periodic ping spikes. How can I figure out what is causing this?

Comment: Your output does not show every third ping is slow.  It looks like your WiFi is congested and the WiFi interface in your phone is not very good (but it could be something else) Try moving your phone close to your AP and retesting. Also try getting a task killer and killing all tasks and see if that clears the problem (which could indicate a CPU bottleneck)

Comment: I've used this phone with the router without problems until recently (last few months). I think it coincided with the update to Android 9. If I move closer to the access point, I'll end up on the 5Ghz network which works fine. Other people seem to have a [similar](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/14981665?hl=en) problem. I have reinstalled the OS from scratch today using factory reset so there are minimal apps...

Comment: Sounds like an issue in the (firmware for the) radio in your phone.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nightmare as it's rendered my phone useless at home. I'm going to try a custom ROM now. Wifi strength is -65 dB with my network being the only one in the area.

Comment: Don't forget that in the 2.4 GHz band not only WiFi is located. It is free to use and therefore used by many different devices and systems. It is possible that even the Bluetooth part of your phone has an negative effect on the WiFi part.

Comment: Well that would suck. We have a few devices in the house - Firestick, Echo, another phone and a laptop. I am currently at least 10m from any of these. Installed Lineage OS 17.1 and still getting spikes but they have decreased.

Comment: Disable Bluetooth on your device and test again. Also don't forget to check for a potentially present Babyphone, video doorbell, wireless headset, wireless audiobridge. Additionally "cheap China light-bulbs" (energy saving lamps as well as LED lamps with integrated power converter from 110/230V) can cause high frequency interference.